# The class has no property or method named '...'. MATLAB error

Tags: c#, matlab, call, .net-assembly, out

I am trying to call a C# dll in MATLAB.

Here my C# dll:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace dllForMatlab
{
  public class Class
  {
    public void MultipleOut(int in1, int in2, out int out1, out int out2)
    {
        out1 = in1 * in2;
        out2 = in1 + in2;    
    }
  }
}
```

Here my MATLAB code:

```
NET.addAssembly('the path\dllForMatlab.dll');
in1=5;
in2=3;
[out1, out2] = dllForMatlab.Class.MultipleOut(in1, in2);
```

I use MATLAB R2011b and I got that error "The class dllForMatlab.Class has no property or method named 'MultipleOut'."

I don't understand why I can not call the MultipleOut method.

Is there anybody who has an idea about reason of that problem?

Comment: Just a guess, but your function call does not match your function signature. Your DLL is expecting 4 arguments and a void return but you are calling with 2 arguments and expecting 2 returns.

Comment: You probably need to make your C# method `static`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I made it 'public static void' but I got the same error.

Comment: @sigara: Try to call it with a matching method signature. I know this is not what you wish to do, but it may narrow your issue down. Try calling it in MATLAB with `dllForMatlab.Class.MultipleOut(in1, in2, out1, out2)`

Comment: @grovesNL I tried your way but again I got the same error.

Comment: @sigara: Did you try that method signature while the method was marked as `static`?

Comment: @grovesNL Yes, but I got same error.

Comment: @sigara: Can you try using `methods dllForMatlab.Class` to check if it's doing something else?

Comment: @grovesNL I run the code in your last comment. The result: Methods for class dllForMatlab.Class:
Class        GetType      addlistener  findobj      gt           lt           
Equals       MultipleOut  delete       findprop     isvalid      ne           
GetHashCode  ToString     eq           ge           le           notify. Here we can see 'MultipleOut' but I have no idea why I can not call that method :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example

#### example.cs

```cs
using System;

namespace MyNS
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void myFunc1(int in1, int in2, out int out1, out int out2)
        {
            out1 = in1 * in2;
            out2 = in1 + in2;    
        }

        public static void myFunc2(int in1, int in2, out int out1, out int out2)
        {
            out1 = in1 * in2;
            out2 = in1 + in2;    
        }
    }
}
```

We compile the above as an assembly:

```
C:\> csc.exe /target:library example.cs
```

#### MATLAB

```
>> NET.addAssembly('C:\path\to\example.dll');

% static class method
>> [a,b] = MyNS.MyClass.myFunc2(10,20)
a =
         200
b =
          30

% member method
>> obj = MyNS.MyClass;
>> [a,b] = obj.myFunc1(10,20)
a =
         200
b =
          30
```

Comment: related doc page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-net-methods-with-out-keyword.html